# Unable to pass arguments to button methods in jasmine using vue and moment

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a Vue app I am trying to unit test, using `jasmine`/`karma`. Below is the code in a component:

After using `v-for=(data,index)` from database, I'm setting `data.date` in the template:

```html
<p class="date">
  {{ dateFilter(data.date) }}
</p>
```

Now I can test whether a given data is in the proper format. I currently have something like this in the spec file:

```js
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import moment from 'moment'

it('should call method', () => {
  const selector = wrapper.find('date');
 
});
```

How can I call the method and pass a mock parameter to test the method? Can we also import the moment js?

Comment: What if you move your `dateFilter()` method contents to a function, that would expect 2 arguments `function formatUtcDate(date, format)` and you'll need to test it separately from Vue component method. Then you would use that function in `dateFilter` method of your component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To test whether the date was rendered in the correct format:

```js
const wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {
  propsData: {
    // assuming component has `items` prop, used in:
    // <p class="date" v-for="data in items"> {{ dateFilter(data.date) }} </p>
    items: [
      {
        id: 100,
        date: new Date('2020-12-10T12:30:45-08:00') // 12:30pm GMT-8 === 4:30pm UTC
      }
    ]
  }
})

const dateEl = wrapper.find('.date') // find first dateElement with `date` class
expect(dateEl.text()).toEqual('16:30 pm')
```

To test the component method directly, access the method through the wrapper's [`vm` property](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#properties):

```js
expect(wrapper.vm.dataFilter(new Date('2020-12-10T12:30:45-08:00'))).toEqual('16:30 pm')
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not use a method there in the first place. You should use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) instead

```
computed: {
    dateFilter() {
      return moment.unix(this.data.date).utc().format("HH:mm a");
    },
}
```

**in the template**

```
 <p class="date">
      {{ dateFilter }}
 </p>
```

Now in the test you can change the value of data.date (I guess you pass it as a prop)

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import moment from 'moment'

const wrapper = mount(YourComponent)


 it('should call method', () => {

      const localThis = { date: <date-here> }
      expect(wrapper.computed.numbers.call(localThis)).toBe(<experct-result-here>)
 
  });
```

**UPDATE**

To "solve" the problem of iterating elements requiring to pass the argument, the Vue way would be to create a component eg.  and put the logic in that. it could take a data props and act like this:

```
Parent.vue
<display-date v-for="(data,index)in allData" :key="data.id||index" :data-prop="data" />
```

Then inside the display-date component you can use the logic suggested before. Please be aware of the powerful differences between computed properties and methods.

Enjoy coding!

Comment: There you go. But it's a somewhat bold claim saying that `dateFilter` **should** be a `computed`. I do agree with you for what we have seen, but OP could have a larger database that uses the `dateFilter` method.

Comment: Agree, but it would be a somewhat not pure use of the framework. 
Computed Properties are way more efficient because how they cache their result and re-render the tempate just when the value returned is different. 
Methods instead run at every update, so with a large amount of data it would compromise performances heavily. 
Best in that case is to create a litttle component with his own state just to display the date.

Comment: but here from template i want to send the data.date from the template with out using the filters or compute bcoz in front end for getting these results i am first looping the result and then i am getting the data.date

Comment: Again, it's not how it works. Template should render only. Logic is inside the methods and computed. But you can use the same approach with the local this to test methods using your implementation